Can I make bread using apple juice that I put bread yeast in?
I've found a bread at the store I really like that says is has cider in it for an ingredient and wanted to create my own so after the apple juice was bubbling away (took a couple days) I mixed some in bread flour and added water until I had a dough ball.
Now I'm wondering did I use enough of the apple juice or was it okay to use extra water. Will it rise overnight? I wanted to make some rolls or perhaps a baguette in the morning. What temperature should I cook it at?
How should I add rosemary?

Welcome! Can you please explain: did you use juice and added yeast and then left it for a while or did you mix everything immediately? I don’t understand the “bubbling away / a few days “ part? Please give us the whole recipe you were using (if you didn’t use a recipe, then estimate please) and the procedure.

First I drank half a bottle of apple juice over the course of a few days. I let the remaining juice sit in a closet until it was at room temperature. I added to it a pinch of yeast and left the cap on loose making sure air could escape. Two days later it was bubbling away like a carbonated soda. I would shake it to release the extra gas. (It was important to make the bottle half empty because lots of bubbles.) On the third day I poured about a cup of the hard juice with flour and then added water it make enough dough for 3 large buns. After resting for an hour I kneaded the dough and

added rosemary and the dough became elastic and pulled together. Like it stopped sticking to my hands. The next morning the dough has risen. So I shaped it and let it rest for 90 minutes. Then I baked it in a 375 oven until golden brown. It rose more in the oven and right now is cooling and I'm hoping it's cooked all the way through.

it worked the flavor is mild but good. But the bigger rolls where not cooked all the way through.

I had some more of the apple juice left so I did it again this time cooked at 370 for 30 minutes and it fully cooked.  For some reason this bread made my gas alarm go off.

I had some more of the juice left so I'm making more bread again. If I want to make a full sized loaf what do I do?

It may help to say where you are; in some places ‘cider’ refers only to the alcoholic drink, in others to apple juice whether fermented or not, in others only to unfermented.
